# Inappropriate date format in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have time input field i am getting Thu Jan 01 1970 12:59:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) like this i want only time .why i am getting like this is there any issue in time picker in angularjs any one help me out?

```js
function HistoryCtrl($scope) {

     $scope.updateForm = function () {
        console.log($scope.booktime);
       //here i am getting Thu Jan 01 1970 12:59:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
        
    };

    
}
```

```html
<div ng-app ng-controller="HistoryCtrl">
    
     <div class="col">
            <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <span class="input-label" >Time</span>
            <input type="time" ng-model="booktime" name="booktime" min="09:00:00" max="21:00:00" required="">
            </label>
            <div class="form-error" ng-messages="projectForm.booktime.$error">
               <div class="form-error" ng-message="required">* Mandatory</div>
               <div class="form-error" ng-message="min">Booking times: 9am - 9 pm</div>
               <div class="form-error" ng-message="max">Booking times: 9am - 9 pm</div>
            </div>
         </div>
   
    <button ng-click="updateForm()">Update</button>
   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angularjs has a `$filter` service which provides date formatting.

For you convenience I'm providing a sample below:

```
function HistoryCtrl($scope, $filter) {

     $scope.updateForm = function () {
        console.log($filter('date')($scope.booktime, 'mediumTime'));          
    };
}
```

You can go through [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) link to have your desired format of time.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: i am getting error Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: 11:32:00 amFilterProvider <- 11:32:00 amFilter
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/unpr?p0=11%3A32%3A00%20amFilterProvider%20%3C-%2011%3A32%3A00%20amFilter
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:63)

Comment: how can i pass $scope.booktime =data.Scheduled_Time;

Comment: again i need to pass this value to time input filed its not picking

Comment: I'm not getting any error. Please see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dosxn14c/

Comment: okey i have seen if i pass like this $scope.booktime ="15:00" its not pickinghttp://jsfiddle.net/dosxn14c/1/ check this

Comment: Have a look at this please http://jsfiddle.net/nbqo17xm/. Its working properly I guess.

Comment: i want to pass this value 15:00 to $scope.booktime.here its showing --:--:--

Comment: I can't understand what you are actually trying to do. But I think the answer is complete against you question. So, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use moment.js for handle datetime.

http://momentjs.com/

Or use

https://github.com/urish/angular-moment for angularjs

**Format Dates**

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // September 15th 2015, 10:30:07 am
moment().format('dddd');                    // Tuesday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Sep 15th 15
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2015 escaped 2015
moment().format();                          // 2015-09-15T10:30:07+05:30
Relative Time
moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 4 years ago
moment("20120620", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 3 years ago
moment().startOf('day').fromNow();        // 11 hours ago
moment().endOf('day').fromNow();          // in 13 hours
moment().startOf('hour').fromNow();       // 30 minutes ago
Calendar Time
moment().subtract(10, 'days').calendar(); // 09/05/2015
moment().subtract(6, 'days').calendar();  // Last Wednesday at 10:30 AM
moment().subtract(3, 'days').calendar();  // Last Saturday at 10:30 AM
moment().subtract(1, 'days').calendar();  // Yesterday at 10:30 AM
moment().calendar();                      // Today at 10:30 AM
moment().add(1, 'days').calendar();       // Tomorrow at 10:30 AM
moment().add(3, 'days').calendar();       // Friday at 10:30 AM
moment().add(10, 'days').calendar();      // 09/25/2015
Multiple Locale Support
moment().format('L');    // 09/15/2015
moment().format('l');    // 9/15/2015
moment().format('LL');   // September 15, 2015
moment().format('ll');   // Sep 15, 2015
moment().format('LLL');  // September 15, 2015 10:30 AM
moment().format('lll');  // Sep 15, 2015 10:30 AM
moment().format('LLLL'); // Tuesday, September 15, 2015 10:30 AM
moment().format('llll'); // Tue, Sep 15, 2015 10:30 AM
```